# Select count(*)... mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this one :

```
id : name : point 
 1   john      30
 2   james     30
 3   owen      20
 4   mikel     20
 5   jenny     20
 6   kobi      10
```

how I can use the count() function to select * who have point like 20 and less than 20 and > 20

```
select (*) from table_name where point like 20 // return 3
select (*) from table_name where point < 20 // return 1
select (*) from table_name where point > 20 // return 2
```

how I can those 3 query in one to return a table

```
Count(*)
________
   3
   1
   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(point = 20),
       sum(point < 20),
       sum(point > 20)
from table_name;
```

Also, don't use `like` with numbers!  It converts the values to strings.  That could produce unexpected results and might make the query unable to use indexes.

Comment: Thx helpfull :) , second thanx for `like` advice :) !

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from(select count(id) from table_name where point = 20
union
select count(id) from table_name where point < 20 
union
select count(id) from table_name where point > 20 
)a
```

try to this